# Efficient algorithm for finding N min values in a min pairing-heap

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, heap, pairing-heap

I'm using the pairing heap implementation found here: https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/commits/dev/include/jemalloc/internal/ph.h

Once in a while though I need to iterate over the N min values in the heap (where N is bound by the number of elements in the heap but usually less). Is there any efficient way of doing this?

My current approach is calling `remove_first()` N times and then pushing all the popped elements back via `insert()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is `O(k log n)`, where `k` is the number of items you want to print and `n` is the number of elements in the heap. It looks like these operations have been optimized quite extensively in the implementation you're using. There is a way to traverse the heap with another heap to solve your goal in `O(k log k)` instead, which is faster with the log factor on `k` instead of `n`. The approach is fairly simple: Maintain a min-heap of values (with pointers to the nodes in the tree) initialized to the root (which is the minimum value in the heap). Then, you can pop off the auxiliary heap and insert the current node's children in the main heap, which is faster since only the nodes which could possibly be the next smallest value are in the queue (which are the neighbors of the nodes you've taken so far).

While the big-O complexity of this approach is technically better, it will almost certainly be much slower in practice. The implementation of this min-pairing heap seems very efficient, and it would almost certainly outweigh the overhead of creating an auxiliary heap and performing this search. Not to mention the extra code complexity with the possibility of introducing bugs, it's probably not worth it.

I'm pretty sure that you can't do better than `O(k log k)`. My intuition for this is that there's probably a constant time reduction to sorting if you could do better, but comparison-based sorting (iirc) has been proven to be impossible to solve in faster than `O(n log n)`. This intuition could be wrong, but I think it's probably pretty close to the truth. Best of luck!

Comment: With a pairing heap, the root may have multiple children, not just two, and they aren’t necessarily in sorted order. (Unless I’m mistaken?) Does your approach still work given this?

Comment: Good catch! Doesn't affect the solution, just edited the one part in the explanation that affected. The approach still works because of the heap property, which is what the search is working on.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the auxiliary binary heap you’re constructing only has k items in it? For example, what happens if the pairing heap has n nodes, where one node is the root and n-1 of the nodes are direct children of the root?

Comment: For the record what I finally did to get the performance I needed was to spread out the operation across multiple iterations. In each iteration I pop some values out of the heap and push them onto a temp heap. Once N items are popped I merged the two heaps together. Any access to the heap during the the interim state (delete, add, pop) had the required logic to figure out which of the two heaps to access.